# Как восстановить работу приложения после нажатия HOME?

Tags: android, java

Я пишу игру. Она состоит из нескольких Activity. Первым запускается Menu, затем Game. Когда запущена Game я нажимаю кнопку Home, происходит выход на рабочий стол телефона, снова зажимаю кнопку Home, выбираю свою игру и она заходит в Menu, а я бы хотел, чтобы игра продолжалась (возвращались в Game). Кто знает как исправить проблему? Если можете опишите, пожалуйста, еще как сделать, чтобы вернувшись в игру была открыта другая Activity - Pause. Спасибо.

**UPD:**
MenuGameActivity - это активити, названое мной Menu, а TeachGameActivity названное Game
Вот лог операций Активити

DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onCreate()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onStart()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onResume()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onPause()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onCreate()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onStart()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onResume()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onStop()

---

Здесь я нажимаю Home

---

DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onSaveInstanceState()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onPause()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onStop()

---

Здесь я снова открываю игру с помощью Home. Странно, что сразу вызывается метод onDestroy()

---

DEBUG/Activityes(201): TeachGameActivity: onDestroy()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onRestart()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onStart()  
DEBUG/Activityes(201): MenuGameActivity: onResume()

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить метод onResume(); на главной активити и в нем написать уже нужную переадресацию.

Comment: т.е. из главной активити в методе onResume() заново запускать Game?
У меня есть логи работы активити. Сейчас обновлю сообщение может пригодится. Мне их поведение кажется странным. Они ведут себя не так, как я думал.

Comment: подскажете еще почему не вызывается onRestoreInstanceState(...); ?

Comment: может это и не правильный подход, но я бы делал так, в игровом активи в методе онДестрой - сохранял бы состояние игры, например, в  проперти, и вызывал какой-то метод стоп или пауза, ну а в методе онРейзьюм - восстанавливал состояние из сохраненного.
тут ответ на твой вопрос по onRestoreInstanceState() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574462/why-onrestoreinstancestate-never-gets-called